# C mysql prepared statement inserting null character

Tags: mysql, c

I'm trying to set up a prepared statement based on some examples I found on the web. I just want to protect against SQL injections in the name= and description=, but the problem is that when the statement runs it inserts null data

```c
  char* my_str = "ABCDF";

  char *stmt_str = "INSERT INTO notes (name, description) VALUES(?,?)";
  MYSQL_STMT *stmt;
  MYSQL_BIND ps_params[2];
  my_bool is_null;
  int status;

  while(curr != NULL) {
    stmt = mysql_stmt_init(con);
    mysql_stmt_prepare(stmt, stmt_str, strlen(stmt_str));

    memset(ps_params, 0, sizeof(ps_params));

    /* set up CHAR parameter */
    ps_params[0].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
    //ps_params[0].buffer = (char *)&my_str;
    ps_params[0].buffer = &my_str;
    ps_params[0].buffer_length=strlen(my_str);
    ps_params[0].is_null = 0;
    ps_params[0].length = 0;

    ps_params[1].buffer_type = MYSQL_TYPE_STRING;
    //ps_params[1].buffer = (char *)&my_str;
    ps_params[1].buffer = &my_str;
    ps_params[1].buffer_length=strlen(my_str);
    ps_params[1].is_null = 0;
    ps_params[1].length = 0;

    mysql_stmt_bind_param (stmt, ps_params);
    mysql_stmt_execute(stmt);
```

Once it executed I see the following data ( It's a bunch of records in my DB ) after executing it many times

[image: DB]

Answer (score 1):

`my_str` is already a pointer to the string, you shouldn't take its address. You're storing the pointer's value rather than the string value.

```
    ps_params[0].buffer = my_str;
```

Comment: Missed that... Thank you so much!